# MYSQL [string escaping issue]

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, escaping

So , right at the problem spot:
i escape `{char[']=byte[0x27]}` into `{char[\\']=byte[0x5C]}`, and this is INSERTED into a table as blob;

I also escape `{char[]=byte[0x00]}` into `{char[0]=byte[0x30]}`.

When i GET the blob data i just saved, instead of finding this `{char[\\']=byte[0x5C]}` i find this `{char[]=byte[0x00]}`. WHY?

I'm using MysqlConnector for c++ under VS[2015]. Thank you!

Comment: never, ever use string escaping when communicating with a database. Use a prepared statement.

Comment: So, how do i undo-escaping when i GET the blob?

Comment: if you don't escape it going in, it won't be escaped coming out. If you're using GetBlob() be careful when reading data out of the ostream. you need to set it to `noskipws` mode. And don't forget to delete any pointer (including to an ostream) that mysqlcppconnector gives you when you're done with it. Note that prepared statements pass data directly into the database. No escaping is necessary at all. The connector takes care of it all for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.Thanks!

Comment: Hey, how do i get unsigned char array into an std::istream ?

Comment: into or out of? probably better to open a new question at this point, with example code. I'll look out for it.

Comment: i have unsigned char* details1,size=32. so how do i get the [blob] std::istream ?

Comment: `sql::PreparedStatement` has `setBlob` and `sql::ResultSet` has `getBlob`

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. question CLOSED!